# Vifm in Windows 7 x64 filetype default for OS

Tags: windows-7, windows, vim, filetype

I was looking around for a file manager that has Vim key bindings and worked with Windows and that resulted in me discovering about "Vifm"

Problem is (besides the fact it can't be fullscreen-maximized) is it can't open up any files. I keep getting the:

> 'vim' is not recognized as an internal or external program..... press any key to continue

(cmd) dialog window.

[image: screenshot]

Basically what I want it to do is open up what ever default program any extension may be in Windows 7 x64 as within Vifm.

if there are any other (windows compatible) file manager that has Vi key bindings, please list them all down.

Answer (score 2):

Vifm is invoking Vim as just `vim`, and assumes it is accessible through your system's `PATH`, which does not seem to be the case.

The Vim installer (`C:\Program Files\vim\vim74\install.exe`) has an option to install `vim.bat` wrapper scripts into `C:\WINDOWS`; you can re-execute the installer to add those. Alternatively, append the Vim installation directory to your (user or system) `PATH` environment variable (through the Control Panel).

Answer (score 1):

Ingo is right about the way vim is called by default, there is just no really good way of doing it on Windows (`vim` works well on Unix-like systems). You should know that there are simpler ways to accomplish what you want than modifying `PATH` environment variable or installing `vim.bat`. Here is a quick guide:

1. First you need to setup a configuration file. It can be placed under `%HOME%` or `%USEPROFILE%` directories. The simple way to find default location on your system is to run `:echo $VIFM` command inside vifm. You can use `data/vifmrc` file as an example (though, it's mostly Linux-oriented), just copy it to configuration directory.
2. Now you can configure actual command to run Vim.  It's done using `vicmd` option (at the top of the sample `vifmrc`). An example:

   `set vicmd=e:/programs/editors/vim/vim73/gvim.exe`

   (spaces in the path might make it a bit different).
3. The sample `vifmrc` also contains this commented out line closer to the bottom of the file:

   " filetype * start, explorer

   Just uncomment it to open files with standard Windows associations by default.
4. Don't forget to reopen vifm, or try using `:restart` command to reload configuration file.

> besides the fact it can't be fullscreen-maximized

Actually, vifm can, it's `cmd.exe` that stands in the way. Use properties of a running console window (see context menu of an icon in the left top corner) to change window dimentions. You can quickly check that vifm supports resizing by changing size using `:set columns+=1` and `set lines+=1` commands. Alternatively, use something like ConEmu or Console2 instead of `cmd.exe` to run vifm, those are nice replacements of standard console.

> If there are any other (windows compatible) file manager that has Vi key bindings, please list them all down.

Sorry, I can't name any, this is kinda a reason why vifm supports Windows.

Comment: Is it possible to specify a relative path in "set vicmd=..." ?
I didn't manage how to do it.

Comment: @EdPavlov It only makes sense if it becomes absolute on startup (instead of being relative to cwd of a pane), so I assume that's what you're asking about.  You can use a command like `let &vicmd = $VIFM . '/../vim/vim90/gvim.exe'`.

Comment: My idea is to make it relative to vifm.exe itself (I am on Windows). I created an environment that is stored in a git repository so that I can deploy it in seconds. Specifying the path to Neovim in vifmrc is much more convenient than not to forget to add it to the $PATH environment variable after deployment.

Comment: @EdPavlov If you're putting `vifmrc` next to `vifm.exe`, `$VIFM` will point to the directory of `vifm.exe`.