# vifm: Windows-formatted filename from %c macro

Tags: windows, vifm

I'm trying to set up a mapping to open a file with the OS-default application. I don't want to use the filetype command in my vifmrc, as explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/698703/vifm-in-windows-7-x64-filetype-default-for-os), because I want `l` and `Enter` to still open the file with vim. (I still have too many Notepad associations sticking around.) So I tried the following mappings:

```
map o :!start "" "%d\%c"
map o :!start "" "%d\%c:gs?\ ? ?"
```

But, using either one on **File with Spaces.docx**, I get the error message

`Windows cannot find 'c:\path\subpath\File\ with\ Spaces.docx'...`

How do I get the filename into a Windows-friendly format, without the backslashes in the filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of `%{x}` macros have additional `%"{x}` form to work around inability of cmd.exe to handle proper escaping ([docs](https://vifm.info/vimdoc.shtml#vifm-%25c)).

Try the following (you want `noremap` most of the time instead of `map` and using of `:p` filename modifier is more universal than combining `%d` and `%c`):

```
noremap o :!start "" %"c:p
```